# API Calls Status as per Logged in User in Azure APIM

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

Is there a possibility for capturing the status of API calls by the signed-in user to the developer portal in Azure APIM?

Whoever signs in to the developer portal and consumes API, we need the status of which user consumed API - this number of times?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the azure api management activity log and can see all the api status. It will log POST/PUT/DELETE but it will log your GET operations

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-azure-monitor#activity-logs

Comment: Hey, I've tried that, but not getting as expected. I want to see which user is hitting which API, how many times. Even though the signed-in user is someone else, not me, the activity log is showing the event initiator me only.

Comment: @NavjotSingh its better to write your own log with your requirement logged in user , how many times api getting hit and other information